# angular nested form validation setPristine on subForm -> setPristine on parentForm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a parent form containing multiple sub forms (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/riemersebastian/9zr00ear/3/)

When the user changes any of the fields, the respective sub form and the parent form get the class ng-dirty to indicate something has changed.

I have also a save-button (actually it is a link) on each of the sub form which saves all sub-form changes and calls subform.$setPristine to update the state of the subform.

However, I would like the parent form to also take notice when there are no dirty subforms anymore and thus remove its' ng-dirty class.

I have come up with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/riemersebastian/9zr00ear/3/

As you can see I manually check in the controller using jQuery if there are any subforms left marked as dirty, and if not I set the parent form pristine. For that I need to delay the jQuery using $timeout otherwise the call of $setPristine might not have yet changed the DOM and thus the parent form would not be updated.

I would like to know, is there a better way of doing this?

Here is the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {          
    $scope.setFormPristine = function(subForm) {
        console.log(subForm);
        subForm.$setPristine();    

        $timeout(function() {
        if (!($('body').find(".subForm").is(".ng-dirty"))) {
           console.log("none is dirty, set main form pristine")
           $scope.form.$setPristine();
        }
        }, 10);
    }    
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

---

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">            
        <div>
            (outer) form is dirty? <b>{{ form.$dirty }}       </b>
        </div>
        <form name="form" ng-init="variants = [{duration:10, price:100}, {duration:30, price:200}]">
            <div>
                <div class="subForm" ng-repeat="variant in variants" ng-form="subForm">
                 <div>
                    <label>Duration:</label>                    
                    <input name="duration" ng-model="variant.duration"/>                    
                 </div>                  
                 <div>
                    <label>Price:</label>
                    <input name="price" ng-model="variant.price"/>                  
                </div>
                 <a href="" ng-click="setFormPristine(subForm)">Reset Form to pristine</a>
                 <div>
                    (inner) subform is dirty? <b>{{ subForm.$dirty }}           </b>
                 </div>
                  <br></br>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </form>        
    </div>        
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARG! Get that jquery out! ;)

My first solution would be directives and controller api's to have the sub form push notifications to the main form, some pseudo code:

```
    app.directice('mainForm', function($scope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        controllerAs: 'mainCtrl',
        controller: function($scope){
            this.publishState = function (childIsDirty) {
                if (!$scope.parentForm.$dirty && !childIsDirty)
                    $scope.parentForm.$setPristine();
                if (childIsDirty) {
                    $scope.parentForm.$setDirty();
                }
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'parentForm.html'
    };
});

app.directice('subForm', function ($scope) {
    return {
        require: '^parentForm',
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        controllerAs : 'viewModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentForm) {
            console.log("Hey I am subForm!");
            scope.$watch('subForm1.$dirty', function(isDirty, wasDirty) {
                parentForm.publishState(isDirty);
            });
        },
        controller : function() {
            var viewModel = this;
            viewModel.myData = "Hello World";
        },
        templateUrl: 'subForm.html'
    };
});
```

With the html you should steer clear of nesting the forms, considered bad html form (sorry, had to do it), they really don't need to be anyways since the required command will just look at all the other controllers that have been injected.

```
<div>
    <parent-form></parent-form>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="parentForm.html">
        <form name="parentForm">
            content
        </form>
        <form name="subForm1" sub-form></form>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="subForm.html">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="viewModel.myData" >
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

You can also pass in the main form method into the scope '&' of the sub form if you dont want to link.

The other way is to create a shared service/factory that you use to pubsub the changes and then the form controllers would watch the properties or registering their methods to the singleton factory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please give me some time to look into it, as I have yet to try it out!

Comment: I've created a plunkr with your sample code, please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/FqrIGihxHKlEzErqts5J?p=preview

I am currently stuck with the problem, that the subForm.html when included in the parentForm, does not have the <form> tag within, i.e. the resulting html-code from the 2 nested directives is:
    <parent-form>
 <form name="parentForm" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  ...        
        <sub-form>
   <div>    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some text">            
   </div>
  </sub-form>
  ...
    </form></parent-form>
Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I try to post the code here again:
    `<parent-form>
    <form name="parentForm" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    ...        
        <sub-form>
      <div>    
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some text">            
            </div>
        </sub-form>
    ...
    </form></parent-form>`

Comment: So took your example and was able to make it work with some minor improvements, should work just fine, I would also look into ngModelOptions to handle when the notifications happens (i.e. on blur not keystroke).  You will also need to parameterize the child watch based on the child form name.

Comment: Pardon me for not responding - could you please post the link to the example with your improvements so I can check it out? Thanks!

Comment: @SebastianRiemer here is a plunker, as you can see the child form is communicating to the parent form on its state, you can track in the parent form the state of N amount of child forms.  http://plnkr.co/edit/b2pJFMKmNRs4dOjpV6Cx?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I can see now how all of it works together and the example helps a lot!